# how can i get all Images from this firebase JSON database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[JSON Image Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i2TTe.png)

i want to get all the images from my firebase database with this code

```
FirebaseDatabase mFirebaseInstance = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();


    mFirebaseInstance.getReference("actors").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this, you need to loop through the `DataSnapshot` object using `getChildren()` method. So please use the following lines of code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
Query query = rootRef.child("actors").orderByChild("image");
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String image = ds.child("image").getValue(String.class);
            Log.d(TAG, image);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.d(TAG, databaseError.getMessage());
    }
};
query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

The output in your logcat, will be all the image urls.

Comment: please answer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51986711/how-can-i-add-a-string-with-multiple-data-to-string-array

Comment: I'll take a look and if I'll know the answer, I'll write it to you.

Answer (score 0):

You can better use `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` instead of `addValueEventListener` as it will be called once so it will be very helpful, please try below code

```
ArrayList<String> arr_imageList = new ArrayList<>();


DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

reference.child("actors").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        arr_imageList.clear();
        if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {

            for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1 : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                ActorsModel actorsModel = dataSnapshot1.getValue(ActorsModel.class);

                if (actorsModel != null && actorsModel.getImage() != null) {

                    arr_imageList.add(actorsModel.getImage());
                }
            }

        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```

and please add model class for ActorsModel which is below

```
public class ActorsModel implements Serializable {

    private String children;
    private String country;
    private String description;
    private String dob;
    private String height;
    private String image;
    private String name;
    private String spouse;

    public ActorsModel() {
    }

    public ActorsModel(String children, String country, String description, String dob, String height, String image, String name, String spouse) {
        this.children = children;
        this.country = country;
        this.description = description;
        this.dob = dob;
        this.height = height;
        this.image = image;
        this.name = name;
        this.spouse = spouse;
    }

    public String getChildren() {
        return children;
    }

    public void setChildren(String children) {
        this.children = children;
    }

    public String getCountry() {
        return country;
    }

    public void setCountry(String country) {
        this.country = country;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getDob() {
        return dob;
    }

    public void setDob(String dob) {
        this.dob = dob;
    }

    public String getHeight() {
        return height;
    }

    public void setHeight(String height) {
        this.height = height;
    }

    public String getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(String image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getSpouse() {
        return spouse;
    }

    public void setSpouse(String spouse) {
        this.spouse = spouse;
    }
}
```

Comment: in ActorsModel, this line shows error arr_imageList.add()

Comment: @emeishiwu, have you found any luck?

Comment: it is now free from error, how do i now access the arraylist of strings? like i want to list it in a textView

Comment: Hav you got the arraylist of images ??

Comment: @emeishiwu, whats the problem you are facing ??