# How can i add a String with multiple data to String Array

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

i want to add the string from **actorImages** in MainActivity.java to **String[] getActorsUrls()** in another class

MainActivity.java

```
 DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    Query query = reference.child("actors").orderByChild("image");
    ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                String  actorImages = ds.child("image").getValue(String.class);

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, actorImages, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    };
    query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

ImageUrlUtils.java

```
 public static String[] getActorsUrls() {
    String[] urls = new String[]{
            "string 1,
            "string 2",
    };
    return urls;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to create a method called `addActorUrls(String url)` within `ImageUrlUtils` and then call it within your loop:

```
// looping above
String  actorImages = ds.child("image").getValue(String.class);
ImageUrlUtils.addActorUrls(actorImages);  // This should set our private String[] url property
```

Comment: how can i now get the data from the ImageUrlUtils

Comment: @emeishiwu - Please read up on how getters and setters (sometimes called mutators) should work within Java.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a problem on the urls, try this :D

**ImageUrlUtils.java**

```
 public static String[] getActorsUrls() {
    String[] urls = new String[]{
            "string 1",
            "string 2",
    };
    return urls;
}
```

Hope it works